# Java Swing - JPanel centering issue

Tags: java, swing

Basically, this is the structure of my Window.

[image]

The actual window looks like this:

[image]

My problem is that I want the `MainPanel` with the `ComboBox` and and the rest to fit the `JFrame` window. Stretch horizontally and stick to the top. But I've tried all kinds of layouts (Box, GridBag, Grid). It just remains centered. How do I achieve this?

Here is the MVCC:

```
    import java.awt.CardLayout;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;





    public class simplelayout{
    JFrame mainFrame;
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JPanel innerPanel;
    JPanel createDomainPanel;
    JPanel listDomainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    String comboBoxItems[]={"Create Domain","List Domains"};
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    JComboBox listCombo;
    JButton goBtn;
    CardLayout layout;
    JTextField domainName = new JTextField(); 
    JLabel successMessage = new JLabel("");


    public simplelayout(){
        initialize();
        setCardLayout();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private void setCardLayout() {
        innerPanel = new JPanel();
        //innerPanel.setSize(600, 400);

        layout = new CardLayout(10,10);
        innerPanel.setLayout(layout);

        //Default Panel
        JPanel defaultPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        defaultPanel.add(new JLabel("Welcome to Amazon Simple DB"));

        //Create Domain Panel
        createDomainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        //createDomainPanel.setSize(600, 300);
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;


        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=0;
        createDomainPanel.add(new JLabel("Enter the name of the domain"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=1;        
        createDomainPanel.add(domainName, gbc);

        JPanel result = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        result.add(successMessage);
        gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=2;
        createDomainPanel.add(result, gbc);

        //List Domain Panel
        listDomainPanel.add(new JLabel("List of Domains"), gbc);

        //Add to innerPanel
        innerPanel.add(defaultPanel, "Default");
        innerPanel.add(createDomainPanel, "Create Domain");
        innerPanel.add(listDomainPanel, "List Domain");

        layout.show(innerPanel, "Default");

        DefaultComboBoxModel panelName = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        panelName.addElement("Create Domain");
        panelName.addElement("List Domain");

        listCombo = new JComboBox(panelName);
        listCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);
        JScrollPane listComboScroll = new JScrollPane(listCombo);

        goBtn = new JButton("Go");



        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc1.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc1.anchor=GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

        gbc1.gridx = 0;
        gbc1.gridx = 0;
        mainPanel.add(listComboScroll, gbc1);

        gbc1.gridy = 1;
        mainPanel.add(goBtn, gbc1);

        gbc1.gridy = 2;
        mainPanel.add(innerPanel, gbc1);

        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc2.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc2.anchor=GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        JScrollPane scr = new JScrollPane(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setSize(mainFrame.getPreferredSize());
        mainFrame.add(scr, gbc);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }




    private void initialize() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Amazon Simple DB");
        mainFrame.setSize(700, 500);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        //mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,1));

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            //UIManager.put("nimbusBase", new Color(178,56,249));
            //UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey", new Color(102,212,199));
            //UIManager.put("control", new Color(212,133,102));

            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new simplelayout();

            }
        });

    }
    }
```

Comment: Its not clear what you want. Do you want `mainPanel` to fit the complete frame or more area than it is currently as shown in the pic?

Comment: Yes. I want the MainPanel inside MainFrame to complete fit the window horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the application frame's default `BorderLayout`, placing the combobox & button components in a nested panel in the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` location with the `innerPanel` in the `CENTER` position.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `mainFrame.pack();` in the `initialize()` and the `setCardLayout()`methods, Remove all `mainFrame.setSize()` and `mainPanel.setSize()` methods.

Comment: I already tried that. All it does is open a smaller window the size of the mainPanel even though I want it opened in maximized state. And when I maximize it, it's glued to the top but not stretched horizontally.

Comment: I just edited it- the new edit should work. At least, it works on my computer,

Comment: But if I use the pack statement, it doesn't open in maximized state, which is what I wanted.